# Call procedure with multilple values in one Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this piece of code, and i call it using :

```
EXECUTE get_all_featured @page = 1, @tipoleilao = 2
```

My Objective is to call this procedure and in the arg @tipoleilao to be able to put for example `@tipoleilao = 2 and 1`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_all_featured
@page int,
@tipoleilao int
AS
SELECT *, (rowNum / 8) + 1 as page
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY items.data_exp DESC) as rowNum
    FROM items INNER JOIN utilizadores ON items.autor = utilizadores.id_user WHERE activo = '1' and tipo_leilao = @tipoleilao and sold = '0'
    and featured = '1' and tipo_leilao != 3
) x 
WHERE (rowNum / 8) + 1 = @page
```

How can i do it?

Comment: And how you plan to use it in your SP?

Comment: Look at table valued parameters; that would be the right way to do it. The sloppy way would be to pass a string like `'(1,2)'` and use a dynamic query.

Comment: yep table valued parameters!

Comment: is this the best option=?

Comment: Why do you want to use only one parameter to pass those two values? If you really only have those two values, I suggest using two parameters. If you want to pass a list of an undefined number of values, then, as suggested by outis nihil, check out table parameters.

Comment: Alternative is to pass in the string and parse it into table inside SP with a function.

Comment: Create User Define DataType of Table of column having int values & then pass it to SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is such a great opportunity to reference Erland Sommarskog's [essay](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#tableparam) on this subject.  There are many solutions, and the best one depends on a number of factors.

If the column that you are comparing against is not indexed and you want a quick and easy solution, I would be tempted by the simple comma-separated list:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_all_featured
@page int,
@tipoleilao varchar(255)
AS BEGIN
. . . 

SELECT . . .
WHERE ','+@tipoleilao+',' like '%,'+cast(tipo_leilao as varchar(255))+'%,' . . ..
```

I can hear the groans about this approach, but it does generally require the least amount of coding before calling the stored procedure.  And, it can make it feasible to have a human being input the list of values.

From this simple beginning, you have many options.  You can take a list like this and use a `split()` function on it.  You can create a user defined table type and pass in the variables as a table type.  You could have a common global temporary table shared between the stored procedure and the caller.  And there are no doubt more exotic methods that Erland discusses